# How can I move the database location of Evernote successfully?

Tags: path, database, evernote, folder-redirection

I am currently on Evernote 4.5.x and lost quite some data because I didn't notice that the crashing Evernote deleted recently created notes due to space limitations in my TC container.
I am not happy.

Now worse is that I can't successfully move the database! I put it into "My documents" (as my Dropbox is full) and changed the path afterwards (after closing Evernote), which seemingly was a mistake. Evernote, even though it states the database path, doesn't accept the full database!

How do I get Evernote to accept the existing database, is there any file which I can edit to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!